# SQL query privatemsgs between users GROUP BY ERROR

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I've build the following query:

```
(SELECT 
    privatemsgs.id,
    privatemsgs.useradn,
    privatemsgs.useraid,
    privatemsgs.title,
    privatemsgs.created,
    privatemsgs.timee,
    privatemsgs.isread,
    u.photo AS creatorphoto,
    privatemsgs.relatedto
FROM privatemsgs 
LEFT JOIN
    users AS u ON(privatemsgs.useraid = u.id)
WHERE userbid='5'
    AND relatedto=0 and bdel=1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT
    privatemsgs.id,
    privatemsgs.useradn,
    privatemsgs.useraid,
    privatemsgs.title,
    privatemsgs.created,
    privatemsgs.timee,
    privatemsgs.isread,
    u.photo AS creatorphoto,
    rel.relatedto
FROM privatemsgs AS rel
    JOIN privatemsgs ON(rel.relatedto = privatemsgs.id)
    LEFT JOIN
    users AS u ON(rel.useraid = u.id)
WHERE rel.userbid='5')
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY timee DESC
```

This query select all Privatemsgs from the tables, and acting like mail,FOR EX:

If I sent a msg to user b, and user b answered me. I want to display the msg in inbox and outbox of each user.

A comment to private msg marked as "relatedto" the id of the main msg.

The query works, but duplicate the msgs in display (same msg display many times)
I tried to do "GROUP BY id" in order to fix it but i got the error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY id ORDER BY timee DESC'
```

THANK YOU!!

Comment: in the error-msg it says `GROUP BY relatedto ORDER BY timee DESC` - shouldn't it be `ORDER BY time DESC`instead?

Comment: `GROUP BY relatedto` is not even in the query that you've shown.

Comment: I can't put any GROUP BY statement (not id and not relatedto) i've edited the question

Comment: To use `GROUP BY` (assuming you need it) you may want to wrap your `UNION` into any **outer query** and use `GROUP BY` there.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM ((SELECT ... ) UNION (SELECT ...)) GROUP BY ... ORDER BY...` . While MySql will allow GROUP BY without aggregate functions the result might not be what you expect.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//group-by-extensions.html

Comment: I've got the following error "Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: Please read MySql's group-by-extensions document first (link in my reply above).  If you still want to use GROUP BY after that - give individual aliases to each internal select and to outer select.

Comment: Also, have you tried `UNION` instead of your `UNION ALL`?

Answer (score 0):

First, as per PM 77's comment, a union instead of a union all will solve your problem of duplicates.  You don't need a group by clause at all.

Second, you might have a logic error.  The top have of your union query has this:

```
FROM privatemsgs 
LEFT JOIN
users AS u ON(privatemsgs.useraid = u.id)
WHERE userbid='5'
AND relatedto=0 and bdel=1)
```

If any of those fields in the where clause are in the users table, your left join has become an inner join.  To keep it as a left join, you have to put all the filters in the join, like this:

```
FROM privatemsgs 
LEFT JOIN
users AS u ON privatemsgs.useraid = u.id
AND userbid='5'
AND relatedto=0 and bdel=1)
```